# Socket closes after the device goes into deep sleep - Android Xamarin

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin

I have created a simple TCP server which I use to send notifications to an android app (xamarin).

When the app is in the foreground it works correctly but when I sleep the device (lock the device) after 1-3 minutes I get an error message - "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" from the server and I lose connection.

I have created a service in the android project that takes care of the connection.

Test Server :

```
namespace AsyncServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[2048];
        private static List<connectedUser> Users = new List<connectedUser>();
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket
            (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static int port = 25565;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupServer();
            while (true)
            {

                //Console.WriteLine("pick user name");
                string userText = "User";// Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter");
                string re = Console.ReadLine();

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NotificationOrderModel() { User = "Server", Name = re});
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

                if (Users != null)
                {
                    foreach (connectedUser user in Users.ToList())
                        if (user.Name == userText)
                            Send(user, buffer);
                }


            }

        }

        private static void Send(connectedUser user , byte [] buff) 
        {
            try
            {
                user._clientSocket.BeginSend(buff, 0, buff.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), user._clientSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Users.Remove(user);    
            }
        } 

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("setting server");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            _serverSocket.Listen(5);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {       
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), _serverSocket);
        }
        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
                if (received > 0)
                {
                    byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
                    Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
                    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuf);
                    var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationOrderModel>(data);

                    if (Users != null)
                    {
                        bool flag = false;
                        foreach (connectedUser user in Users.ToList())
                            if (user._clientSocket == socket)
                                flag = true;

                        if (flag)
                            ;
                        else
                        {
                            Users.Add(new connectedUser() { Name = tmp.User, _clientSocket = socket });
                            Console.WriteLine("connected - " + tmp.User); // to be removed
                        }
                    }





                    if (tmp.isPing)
                    {
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NotificationOrderModel() { User = "Server", isPing = true });
                        if (Users != null)
                        {
                            foreach (connectedUser user in Users.ToList())
                                if (user.Name == tmp.User)
                                    Send(user, dataBuf);
                        }
                    }
                    

                }
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex) 
            {
                //when user disconnects - closes the application
            }
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }


    }

    class connectedUser 
    {
        public string Name;
        public Socket _clientSocket;
    }


    public class NotificationOrderModel //:  OrderModel, ICloneable
    {
        public string Name;
        public decimal Qty;
        public string ServingPlace;
        public string User;
        public bool Seen = false;
        public bool isPing = false;

        public NotificationOrderModel()
        {

        }
    }


}
```

Socket service in Android:

```
 [Service]
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(SocketService))]
    public class SocketService : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Ping();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            //if (_cts != null)
            //{
            //  _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            //  _cts.Cancel();
            //}
            base.OnDestroy();
        }


        public static ObservableCollection<NotificationOrderModel> OrderList = new ObservableCollection<NotificationOrderModel>();
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket
           (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[2048];
        private static string IP = App.Settings.ServerIP; 
        private const int port = 25565;
        private static IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        public static bool Connected = false;



        public static async Task<bool> Start()
        {

            if (!Connected)
            {
                //_serverSocket.ReceiveTimeout
                _serverSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), _serverSocket);

                if (_serverSocket.Connected == true)
                    Connected = true;
            }
            try
            {
                if (Connected == true)
                {
                    // Console.ReadLine();
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NotificationOrderModel() { User = App.DataProvider.User.Username, isPing = true });
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json); //"test"
                    _serverSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _serverSocket);
                    _serverSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _serverSocket);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Connected = false;
            }


            return false;
        }
        //initiate 
        //ping
        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndConnect(ar);
                //Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                Connected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                _serverSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), _serverSocket);
                //Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to connect");
            }
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
                if (received > 0)
                {
                    byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
                    Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
                    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuf);
                    var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationOrderModel>(data);
                    if (!tmp.isPing)
                    {
                        OrderList.Add(tmp);
                        // DependencyService.Get<INotification>().CreateNotification("title", "text");                      
                    }
                }
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                //throw;
            }
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }



        private static async Task<bool> Initialized()
        {
            _serverSocket.ReceiveTimeout = -1;
            _serverSocket.SendTimeout = -1;
            _serverSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), _serverSocket);

            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                _serverSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _serverSocket);
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NotificationOrderModel() { User = App.DataProvider.User.Username, isPing = true });
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                _serverSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _serverSocket);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Connected = false;
                // _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); ;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static async Task<bool> Ping()
        {
            if (Connected != true)
                return await Initialized();
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NotificationOrderModel() { User = App.DataProvider.User.Username, isPing = true });
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                    _serverSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _serverSocket);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Connected = false;
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I start the service with this :

```
 var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SocketService));
                StartService(intent);
```

Comment: On some devices like mine(ASUS), the background process killed by OS because of Doze mode or custom battery manager apps. for the first step, you can exclude your app from battery optimization in the device setting, if it helped then you should Ignore battery optimization if not there is a problem with your service.

Comment: Create a Foreground Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: You need to create a ForegroundService to keep this alive. This is what other apps do, such as music apps etc.

Comment: Disabling the battery stopped the socket from closing, but I am still testing I am try to do it using a foreground service. I will update the post when I have finished the tests.